# How to decrease time for request?

Tags: python, tornado

I have a simple example:

```
c = tornadoredis.Client()
c.connect()

class SourceHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@tornado.gen.engine
def get(self):
    pipe = c.pipeline(transactional=True)
    pipe.zadd( 'test1'), 1212, "test" )
    pipe.zadd( 'test2'), 1212, "test" )
    .....
    pipe.zadd( 'testN'), 1212, "test" )
    res = yield tornado.gen.Task(pipe.execute)
    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    self.render("template.html", title="result")
```

time for this request = N * time for zadd operation.

Can I decrease time for this request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipeline request is a transactional request which requires that all operations within it execute as an atomic unit.  The statement - `res = yield tornado.gen.Task(pipe.execute)` will wait until all of the `zadd` statements are executed until it returns execution back to your get(...) function.

The only way that you could decrease execution time is to remove the `gen.engine` bits in a fire and forget pattern, though you'll no longer have any response information.

```
class SourceHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        pipe = c.pipeline(transactional=True)
        pipe.zadd( 'test1'), 1212, "test" )
        pipe.zadd( 'test2'), 1212, "test" )
        ...
        pipe.execute()
        # of course you no longer have the response information...
        ...old code...
```